# Use gremlin module for Python to add vertex to Amazon Neptune graph database

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

#### Synopsis

I am trying to use Python on an Amazon EC2 instance, in the same VPC as an Amazon Neptune instance, to add a vertex (node) to Neptune. Using the [example code for Amazon Neptune](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-python.html), I constructed the following code sample to add a vertex (node) and then print out **all** vertices in the graph.

```
from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph

from pprint import pprint


target = 'zzzzzz-instance-1.zzzzzzzz.us-west-2.neptune.amazonaws.com'
port = '8182'

g = Graph()

remote = DriverRemoteConnection(f'wss://{target}:{port}/gremlin', 'g')
conn = g.traversal().withRemote(remote)
conn.addV('person').property(id, 5).property('firstname', 'Trevor')
print(conn.V().toList())
```

#### Actual Behavior

The invocation to `conn.addV()` silently fails, and the following line with the `print()` statement returns an empty Python list.

#### Expected Behavior

1. The call to `conn.addV()` throws an exception, or ...
2. The call to `conn.addV()` succeeds, and the `print()` line returns the vertex

**Question**: How do I use the Gremlin module for Python to add a vertex to the graph, in Amazon Neptune?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your addV() query needs a Terminal Step such as next() or iterate().  Otherwise, you get the bytecode representation of the query returned.
http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#var